# Using simplexml to parse an RSS2 feed and the commas in media->description are missing. How to get them back?

Tags: php, simplexml

Where did the commas go?
Here's an RSS2 feed url: https://feed.zazzle.com/rss?qs=256295133855961540
and here's the relevant part

```
<media:description>
<![CDATA[ Pink faux glitter drip, pain drip look on a rose gold faux metallic looking background. A pink rose, yellow berries, green foliage and a banner for Your name. The name in pastel pink is written with a modern and trendy hand lettered style script. ]]>
</media:description>
```

By the time I do the following, I've already used simplexml_load_string to load the feed. When I do this:

`echo $myItem->children('media', true)->description;`

to show me its contents, this is what I get:

> Pink faux glitter drip pain drip look on a rose gold faux metallic looking background. A pink rose yellow berries green foliage and a banner for Your name. The name in pastel pink is written with a modern and trendy hand lettered style script.

Where did the commas go and how do I keep them when assigning the description to a variable?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Using the same URL and as far as I can tell similar code and get `Pink faux glitter drip, pain drip look on a rose g...` with the commas.

Comment: I just edited my question for clarity, adding this: By the time I do the following, I've already used simplexml_load_string to load the feed. When I do this:

Comment: What code did you use, @NigelRen?

Comment: `$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://feed.zazzle.com/rss?qs=256295133855961540"); echo $xml->channel->item->children('media', true)->description;`.

Comment: How very, very strange. Yes, that code works for me as well, @NigelRen. I've been using curl followed by a simplexml_load_string to pull in the feed content. Dumping out the results of the curl shows that the commas have gone before the simplexml_load_string is used.
So it seems that curl is the root cause of the missing commas.
Thanks for helping me isolate it. :)